# Push the data into Firestore using firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi i am new firebase functions and trying to push data to firestore, With below code i am able to push message to firestore and it is working,

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
  // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});
```

with this url i am able to push text

```
http://localhost:5001/myProj/us-central1/addMessage?text=sss
```

I need to push some data in array of object in place of text, What changes i have to do with above code.

object like:

```
data: {  booking_id: "0",
         channels: "4",
        country: "GB", 
        date: "2020-05-12",
        currencies: "GBP",
        total: "5000"    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an object in your Cloud Function, you should add it to the body of a POST request and parse it as explained in [this part of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) and fully detailed in this [official Sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/time-server) (see the following [line of code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/3515b7f38a3c598cdb20152a263372e81719ecda/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js#L69)).

More concretely, in the Cloud Function you should do:

```
const booking_id = req.body.booking_id;
const channels = req.body.channels;
//...
```

and to call it via curl you should do as follows:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' /
     -d '{"booking_id": "0", "channels": "4", "country": "GB", ...}' /
     https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/....
```

Comment: in official sample post method is with queryparam, I am looking to pass data in body

Comment: No the two cases are taken into account on the sample: see the following [line of code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/3515b7f38a3c598cdb20152a263372e81719ecda/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js#L69)

Comment: yes got it, is this the way we need to give body:  
 curl  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' /
     -d '{"format": "MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"}'

Comment: Yes, it is explained [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/time-server#try-the-sample) in the sample.

Comment: can you provide answer by adding body to my question

Comment: See the update.