# Firebase functions to add data dynamically

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi i am using firebase functions to add data to firestore, I am able to add data to firestore with below code with static data.

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('payment').add({
    date: new Date(),
    status: true,
    cardNo: "343434343433",
    bookingNumber: 23232,
  })
  .then((doc) => {
    functions.logger.log(`Added CardInfo`, doc);
    return "ok";
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    functions.logger.log(`Fail`, err);
    throw new Error(
      `Ref: failed to add card Info`,
      err
    );
  });
  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult} added.`});
});
```

I am not able to add data if i pass object as below.

```
const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('payment').add({
        date: new Date(),
        status: req.status,
        cardNo: req.cardNo,
        bookingNumber: req.bookingNumber,
      })
```

Comment: "I am not able to add data" What do you exactly mean? it doesn't work at all? It doesn't work the way you want? Did you try to debug the values of `req.status`and `req.cardNo`.

Comment: i am new to  firebase functions, so i am not aware of posting data to firestore

Comment: Can you clarify your last comment? What do you mean by "i am not firebase functions"?

Comment: yes edited my previous comment

Comment: Ok, well noted. But can you debug your code with `console.log(req.status)` and `console.log(req.cardNo)`What do you see in the Firebase console, part "Cloud Functions"

Comment: i am not able to debug, but when i run in postman i am getting error as below in terminal and postman: Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "cardNo")

Comment: What is the exact url you are using? Can you update your question with it?

Comment: http://localhost:5001/projectName/us-central1/addMessage
in postman  body:  as key value pair
status  true
cardNo  32323232

Comment: See my answer to your other question

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628634/push-the-data-into-firestore-using-firebase-functions), you need to pass an object to your Cloud Function by adding this object to the body of a POST request and parse it as explained in this [official Sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/time-server).

*(I cannot mark this question as duplicate of the other answer since I initially voted to close it for lack of debugging info)*

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate on your behalf.